# F# Reflection Expr.NewUnionCase with FSharpType.GetUnionCases and/or Type.MakeGenericType

Tags: reflection, f#, union-types

```
let recordType = ... // omitted
let resultTypeRaw = typedefof<Result<_,_>>
let resultType = resultTypeRaw.MakeGenericType([|recordType.AsType();typeof<string list>|])
Expr.NewUnionCase(
  (* behavior changes between using resultTypeRaw versus resultType on the next line *)
  FSharpType.GetUnionCases(resultType) |> Array.pick (function | x when x.Name = "Ok" -> Some x | _ -> None),
  [
    Expr.NewRecord(
      recordType,
      [
        Expr.Value(5)
      ]
    )
  ]
)
```

When I attempt to use `resultType` with `GetUnionCases` I get the following exception: `Specified method is not supported.`. I presume some F# metadata is lost via the call to `MakeGenericType`.

When I attempt to use `resultTypeRaw`, `GetUnionCases` succeeds but the subsequent `NewUnionCase` fails with the following exception: `Type mismatch when building 'sum': incorrect argument type for an F# union. Expected 'T', but received type {{recordType's name}}`

How can I construct a union type with dynamic generic arguments or use the result of `MakeGenericType` with the `FSharpType`/`Expr` functions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your record contains a single integer field in that example? In this case, the problem might be in the omitted part.

The code seems fine to me and does seem to generate an expression to construct an `Ok` of your record instance.
Here is a slightly amended example that runs fine in F# Interactive:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

open FSharp.Linq.RuntimeHelpers

let eval q = LeafExpressionConverter.EvaluateQuotation q

type TestRecord = { ExampleValue: int }
let recordType = typedefof<TestRecord>
let resultTypeRaw = typedefof<Result<_,_>>
let resultType = resultTypeRaw.MakeGenericType([|recordType; typeof<string list>|])

let expr =
  Expr.NewUnionCase(
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases(resultType) |> Array.pick (function | x when x.Name = "Ok" -> Some x | _ -> None),
    [
      Expr.NewRecord(
        recordType,
        [
          Expr.Value(5)
        ]
      )
    ]
  )

expr |> eval
```

Result:
`val it : obj = Ok { ExampleValue = 5 }`